# Experimenting with Lists: Why can't I reassign an immutable object?

Tags: python, string, list, variables, immutability

In the code below When I reassign the value of name, this change is not reflected in the value of student

Can someone explain the behaviour of these variables?

I am more interested in the process that is saving the "snapshot" of the variable. If someone can, drop a technical term so i can do some digging thanks!

```
name = "jim"
student = name
name = "tim"

print(name) # returns tim
print(student) # returns jim
```

Comment: Assigning a value to a variable affects only *that variable*.  The previous value of the variable plays no part in the process.

Comment: This isn't really a question about mutable vs immutable types; OP would see the same kind of result with `name = [1,2,3]; student = name; name = [4,5,6]`. (Not saying there isn't a suitable duplicate out there, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types isn't it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with immutability. You assigned the current *value* of `name` to the name `student`; you did not "link" the name `student` to the name `name`.

See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, especially the third fact ("Names are reassigned independently of other names").